Are built-in static methods bound?
According to the specification, are built-in Javascript static methods, like Array.from, Object.assign, console.log, etc meant to be bound or do they need to be invoked via the constructor/object?
Consider the following:
const assign = Object.assign;
const o1 = assign({}, {x: 1}); // OK in Chrome & Firefox
const o2 = assign.call(Object, {}, {x: 1}); // saefest, but is it necessary?

Assigning one of these static functions to a variable and invoking without the original context seems fine in the modern browsers I tested, but I often see the use of the more verbose approach of setting this to the original context via Function.prototype.call or Function.prototype.apply.
Is this necessary in practice? I can't find anything on the specification that says whether the above mentioned method and similar ones are "context-free" so to speak, i.e. can be safely called from an aliased variable without setting thisArg.

Array.from should be bound, Object.assign does not need to be bound. console.log is not a static method, however it is bound to the instance

Thank you, and thank you for finding the duplicate question, I didn't search the right terms so did not find it!

Finding the duplicate took me a while myself, I only remembered it because I had answered it :D
